# Bootstrap - Erro Jquery

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Estou tentando realizar algumas confecções em javascript no meu projeto que também utiliza bootstrap e preciso ver o log. Entretanto, mesmo utilizando o código fornecido no próprio site do bootstrap, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem no log e o resto do código não executa:

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

E o código no meu head está assim:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

O que há de errado que não consigo fazer funcionar?

Comment: Renan, alguns recursos do bootstrap precisam do jquery, voce deve referencia-lo também.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ https://jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione o script do `jquery`antes do `bootstrap`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-6cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Resolveu! Só tive que tirar o integrity porque estava dando erro. Obrigado Sorack!